# How to construct my graphic structure in Java using Swing?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, frame, java-canvas

I was wondering if you could help me out with the structure of my program. I'm making a game with Java and I have 2 classes. 1 class is a graphics class that extends JFrame with a paint method:

Graphics Class
paint() and calls various objects that use JFrame as a parameter.
Inside the class is a subclass that implements MouseListener and Mouse Motion Listener which interacts with paint method.

Canvas Class
I was planning to embed the first class into a larger canvas class that would have buttons, panels, and so forth so essentially use the class as a smaller (sub-program) inside a larger program. 
Is this possible/ am I doing this the right way. Whenever I try to call the graphic class inside the canvas class, the graphic doesn't turn up.

```
    public Canvas(){
    graphic = new Graphic(name);

}
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
            canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            canvas.setSize(1500, 1500);
    canvas.setVisible(true);
}
```

}
Any help/guidance would be appreciated. I just want to mainly to know if I'm thinking about graphic programming correctly.

Comment: [for example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html), [and here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html), [and here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/Catalog0261__2D-Graphics.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Canvas` is not "Window".  In order to display anything on the screen, you components must be added to a window delegate.

I would, personally, avoid overriding the `paint` methods of top level containers.  The main reason for this is top level containers are not double buffered and it makes your application less portable.  It's much easier to add a component to other components, a frame is pretty final.

I would also use `JPanel` over Canvas, simply because `JPanel` is double buffered.